# cron job to run every 30 minutes between 2p (14:00) and 10a

Tags: cron

I am trying to create a CRON job that runs every 30 minutes from 2p (14:00) through 10a.  Basically, I am looking to have this job run every 30 minutes except for the hours between 10a - 2p (14:00)

Comment: I tried the following, but its not valid -
*/30 14-10 * * *

Comment: going to try this - */30 14-23,0-10 * * *

Answer (score 1):

This is working

```
*/30 14-23,0-10 * * *
```